# How to convert a GLib.Value of type GStrv (string[]) to a GLib.Variant

Tags: glib, vala

In the following example one class property is of type `Gstrv`.
With `ObjectClass.list_properties()` one can query the `Paramspec` of all properties, and with `get_property()` all properties can be requested as `GLib.Value`. How would I access the Value of type `GStrv` and convert it to a `GLib.Variant`?

My GLib version is slightly outdated, so I do not have the `GLib.Value.to_variant()` function available yet :( .

```
public class Foo: GLib.Object {
    public GLib.HashTable<string, int32> bar;

    public Foo() {

        bar = new GLib.HashTable<string, int32>(str_hash, str_equal);

    }

    public string[] bar_keys { owned get { return bar.get_keys_as_array(); } }
}

int main() {
    var foo = new Foo();
    Type type = foo.get_type();
    ObjectClass ocl = (ObjectClass) type.class_ref ();
    foreach (ParamSpec spec in ocl.list_properties ()) {
        print ("%s\n", spec.get_name ());
        Value property_value = Value(spec.value_type);
        print ("%s\n", property_value.type_name ());
        foo.get_property(spec.name, ref property_value);
        // next: convert GLib.Value -> GLib.Variant :(
    }
    foo.bar.set("baz", 42);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
bar-keys
GStrv
```

Comment: new Variant.strv (my_strv)? GStrv is just an array of strings

Comment: @Zander How would I access the string array via the GLib.Value? Implicite conversion did not work for me: new Variant.strv (property_value) results in `Argument 1: Cannot convert from `GLib.Value' to `string[]'` .

Comment: The following seems to be working :-) . `string?[] values = (string?[]) property_value.peek_pointer();` and then  `var variant = new Variant.strv(values);`. It fails for `values == null`. If someone will make it an answer or has something nicer, I will gladly accept it!

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question :-)

Comment: @ZanderBrown I was hoping there was a better way. And answering ones own question feels a bit lonely :-) . But it actually did not work that way with a newer glib version (`peek_pointer()` would always return `null` ). So my suggestion was wrong. What I am now using is `get_boxed()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `GLib.Value.get_boxed()` seems to be working.

Example:

```
// compile simply with: valac valacode.vala
public class Foo: GLib.Object {
    public GLib.HashTable<string, int32> bar;

    public Foo() {

        bar = new GLib.HashTable<string, int32>(str_hash, str_equal);

    }

    public string[] bar_keys { owned get { return bar.get_keys_as_array(); } }
}

public Variant first_gstrv_property_as_variant(Object obj)
{
        Type class_type = obj.get_type();
        ObjectClass ocl = (ObjectClass) class_type.class_ref ();
        foreach (ParamSpec spec in ocl.list_properties ()) {
                print ("%s\n", spec.get_name ());
                Value property_value = Value(spec.value_type);
                print ("%s\n", property_value.type_name ());
                obj.get_property(spec.name, ref property_value);
                // next: convert GLib.Value -> GLib.Variant
                if(property_value.type_name () == "GStrv") {
                        return new GLib.Variant.strv((string[])property_value.get_boxed());
                }
        }
        return new GLib.Variant("s", "No property of type GStrv found");

}

int main() {
        var foo = new Foo();
        print("%s\n", first_gstrv_property_as_variant(foo).print(true));

        foo.bar.set("baz", 42);
        print("%s\n", first_gstrv_property_as_variant(foo).print(true));

        foo.bar.set("zot", 3);
        print("%s\n", first_gstrv_property_as_variant(foo).print(true));
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
bar-keys
GStrv
@as []
bar-keys
GStrv
['baz']
bar-keys
GStrv
['baz', 'zot']
```

In the generated c-code this looks as follows:

```
_tmp18_ = g_value_get_boxed (&property_value);
_tmp19_ = g_variant_new_strv ((gchar**) _tmp18_, -1);
```

Passing -1 as length to `g_variant_new_strv()` means the string array is considered as null terminated. Inside `g_variant_new_strv()` the `g_strv_length()` function is used to determine the length.

Hopefully it will be useful to someone else someday. :-)